# List all Site Collections in a Farm

Tags: powershell, site-collection

I want to be able to see the number, names, url of all site collections there are in a given farm. Would there be a powershell command to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be a powershell equivalent of `stsadm.exe -o enumsites -url https://sp.root.com > "U:\XML\siteowners.xml"` which is what I use to generate XML for import into Excel to view all top level site collections, the owners, the content db it lives in and the size/quota information.

Comment: All the answers were correct but I loved this one because of the xml formatted output!

Comment: While this answer is correct, stsadm has been deprecated; I posted an answer that shows how to output PowerShell objects as XML.

Comment: Just not on 2010 yet :-(

Answer (score 35):

If all you want is a list of all site collections in the farm, all you have to do is open a PowerShell window, load the SharePoint snapin if you haven't (`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`), and type `Get-SPSite`.

If you want to return the list of site collections for a specific web application, the easiest way is to just pipe it as `Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet | Get-SPSite`.

If you want to grab additional information like boflynn suggested, you can also do this with a pipe; no need to script, or loop: `Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet | Get-SPSite | Select ID, Url`.

You can also easily convert any PowerShell object or object array into XML using the Export-Clixml cmdlet. As an example, here's the previous command to get the ID and Url of all intranet web application sites, piped to an XML file: `Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet | Get-SPSite | Select ID, Url | Export-Clixml c:\intranetsites.xml`

There's many output and conversion options; likewise, you also have the ability to output as a CSV using Export-Csv.

Previous answers are not incorrect, but these are cleaner and shorter ways to do it.

Comment: This can also display the URL for Central Administration: `Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration`

Answer (score 6):

[Get-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx) will return the site collections for you.  If you want more details, you can loop through them for further processing:

```
foreach($site in Get-SPSite) {
    echo $site.Url
    echo $site.ID
    #anything else here
}
```

Comment: I find this was one to be the second best answer as I could add site properties as I wanted.

Comment: Excellent. For a list of values for which can be displayed: `Get-SPSite | Get-Member *` Output formatted on one line:  `foreach($site in Get-SPSite -Limit ALL) { Write-Host ($site.Url + " - " + $site.ID) }`

Answer (score 2):

```
$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
    {
        Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you copy your question title and past it into google search, the first [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2011/03/25/powershell-script-to-display-all-sharepoint-site-collection-administrators-in.aspx) search result will contain a powershell script that describes how to collect site collections. But do not fogive to add `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` command befor your comands.

Comment: Not true, the first link ends up pointing to this very page!