# Recursively loop through all sites and their subsites using powershell? (SP 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have tried many things but I only get the list of all sites in the main site.

```
function LoopThroughSites {

        Param ([string]$url)


        $web = get-SPWeb $url
        $count = $web.Site.Allwebs.Count
        foreach($site in $web.AllWebs)
        {           
        $site.URL
        #LoopThroughSites($site.URL)
        }

        $count
        if ($site.title -eq $null)
        {
        #cls
        }


    }

        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        #$username = 'users\AD_Group'
        $initialUrl = "Https://test.site.com"

        LoopThroughSites($initialUrl)
```

The above code provide only the first level of subsite under root site collection but I want to get all of their subsites recursively.

Any good way to do that using Powershell?

Comment: Have u tried this http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2013/01/25/get-all-subsites-of-a-subsite/

Comment: Yes, that only gets the same results as above but doesn't drill down to the subsites that would be listed.

Comment: What is your goal, to find all site collections & subsites in the Farm or in a particular web app? You can get all Site Collections in a Farm just by using the Get-SPSite cmdlet and passing no parameters; if you want only the Site Collections from a given web app, pipe the Get-SPWebApplication cmdlet with Get-SPSite. Once you have all the SPSite objects you want, you can foreach through them, and use .AllWebs to iterate over their respective subsites (i.e. SPWebs). More info here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/22511/25787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
function GetAllWebs($url)
{
    try
    {
        $w = Get-SPWeb $url;
        Write-Host ([String]::Format("Procesing web {0}",$w.Url)) -foregroundcolor Blue
        if($w.Webs.Count -gt 0)
        {
            foreach($web in $w.Webs)
            {
                $web.Url
                GetAllWebs $web.Url;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ([String]::Format("Error processing web at $url, with Exception: {0}", $_.Exception.Message)) -foregroundcolor Red
    }   
}
```